# How get parent position from child Adapter in android?

Tags: android, listview, position

everybody!
My problem is: Parent Adapter is a ListAdapter and child one is a GalleryAdapter. Needed by clicking on item gallery, show (real)image, but I can't get correct lPosition, ie position of ListAdapter(parent adapter).

```
public class PostListAdapter ex...{
     int lPosition;
     int lPosition=??? 
     .....
     public View getView..{
          ...
          gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int gPosition, long id) {

               activity.mainFragment.startImagePagerActivity(gPosition,lPosition);
               }
          });
     }
}
```

Comment: can u pls post whole code of adapter data.. i mean what u are passing as a collections to display parent view data and child data too ...

Comment: both .. and pls explain it clearly

Comment: user1140237 thanks, I fixed it, by dangVarmit's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use setTag() to add the lPosition to each view that you are creating (or recycling) and then retrieve if in the onItemClick call

```js
public class PostListAdapter ex...{
     int lPosition;
     int lPosition=??? 
     .....
     public View getView..{
          ...
          gallery.setTag(lPosition);
          gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int gPosition, long id) {
               int lPos = (int)parent.getTag();
               activity.mainFragment.startImagePagerActivity(gPosition,lPos);
         }
     });
     }
}
```

Comment: thanks man. id did so, but I have got npe.  Because I've tried getting value from view ie int lPos = (int)view.getTag(); couldn't you say, how to getTag from relativeLayout?

Comment: you should be setting the tag on the gallery, which is passed in to the onItemClick as the AdapterView<?> parent parameter.. not the View view parameter.  make sure you are using parent.getTag()